# Microsft Graph Helper fails in the response

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an ASP.Net App and I recent added login with office 365 consuming Graph Api. It works fine in my local machine and I get token and user info from the Graph Api. But when I deploy the solution in production server I m getting an error in the response from the API. Production server is a virtual windows server 2016

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                }));



        var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
            .Select(u => new {
                u.DisplayName,
                u.Mail,
                u.UserPrincipalName
            })
            .GetAsync();
```

This is the code to get the info from the user, after calling this method I get an exeption with the next error:

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0>Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsyc(System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption)'.

The most rare is that this happen only in the production server, in test server and local machine it works fine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing some dependencies. make sure in your bin folder of the app in production you see the Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll file, sometimes when you deploy things it doesn't update the packages for whatever reason. you should see such a file in your test server and local machines. if not there, copy it over. if it is there, then check that you have the same .net versions installed in prod as you have in other environments. also make sure that in your development environment you have the latest graph api sdk being used.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution to solve this problem was updating the .Net framework version in the server.